# Swap every other char in uneven string

Tags: python

As the title suggests im trying to swap every other character in a string (ex: 'abcd' -> 'badc')

```
def coder(s):
    ns = list(s)
    ns[1::2],ns[::2] = ns[::2],ns[1::2]
    return ''.join(ns)
```

My first attempt seen above worked fine with string that had an even number of characters, but gave the error ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size x to extended slice of size x+1 with uneven numbers

```
def coder(s):
    ns = list(s)
    if len(s)%2==0:
        ns[1::2],ns[::2] = ns[::2],ns[1::2]
    else:
        lastcar = ns[-1]
        ns = ns[:-1]
        ns = coder(ns) + lastcar
    return ''.join(ns)
```

my next attempt works fine but is more complex than I thought it would have to be

How to make this simpler?

Comment: Honestly, this approach is exactly what I would do... Chop off the last charecter to make it even, use the working code, then add the last character back... it works, so why change it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Showed my TA my function and he told me there was a much simpler way but I haven't been able to think of one. I've asked him to show me or hint and says he can't so I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: The itertools answer below is a more generalized solution for any list, not just strings, and is the only alternative I can think of

Answer (score 2):

There are probably about a million different ways to do this in Python. One way would be to just iterate, [as shown here:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/program-to-swap-string-characters-pairwise-in-python)

```
def coder(s):
    ns = list(s)
    for i in range(0, (len(ns) - len(ns)%2) - 1, 2):
        ns[i], ns[i+1] = ns[i+1], ns[i]
    return ''.join(ns)
```

If you want to stick with extended slicing, just stop slicing at the last even digit location:

```
def coder(s):
    ns = list(s)
    end = len(ns)-len(ns)%2
    ns[1::2], ns[:end:2] = ns[:end:2], ns[1::2]
    return ''.join(ns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably combine some known-good snippets that you should be familiar with (and if you're not -- get familiar with them they're crazy useful!)

From the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) list, chunk your string into groups of two, reverse each group, then chain them back together.

```py
import itertools

# from itertools recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if incomplete == 'fill':
        return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    if incomplete == 'strict':
        return zip(*args, strict=True)
    if incomplete == 'ignore':
        return zip(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')

s = "abcde"

def swap_chars(s):
    """
    Swap every other letter of a string, returning the resulting mix.

    >>> swap_chars('abcd')
    'bacd'
    >>> swap_chars('abcde')
    'bacde'
    """

    chunks = grouper(s, 2, fillvalue='')
    return ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(reversed(chunk) for chunk in chunks))
```

Alternatively, you could grab all the even-index characters in one list, all the odd-index characters in the other, and reassemble them with `zip_longest` and `chain.from_iterable` in reverse order.

```py
import itertools

s = 'abcdefghijk'

def swap_chars(s):
    mixed = itertools.zip_longest(s[1::2], s[0::2], fillvalue='')
    return ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mixed))
```

This even generalizes fairly well to groups larger than 2

```py
def swap_n_chars(s, n=2):
    groups = [s[i::n] for i in range(n)]
    mixed = itertools.zip_longest(*reversed(groups), fillvalue='')
    return ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mixed))
```

However you might notice that you've just re-invented `grouper` :)